# Aggregating multiple pins at max zoom level in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, gis, leaflet

I am having some trouble when displaying pins in leaflet when the user is at max zoom level. I am loading the pin locations from a MySQL database.

I am already using MarkerClusterer, and this works fine when the user is zoomed out far enough. The problem is, when a user is at the max zoom level, some pins are so close together they are overlapping.

I have also looked into the OverlappingMarkerSpidifier plugin, but this looks quite ugly when there are around 20-30 pins on one street, as all the pins start overlapping again.

Each pin has an image associated with it. Something I would like to do is somehow aggregate multiple pins into one pin if they are close enough together, and then when the user clicks on the pin, they can browse through the images associated with these aggregated pins. I don't know how I could do this.

Would changing to a spatial database work at all? Or can I somehow aggregate the pins location in the PHP call to the database for pins? Or could I do it in JavaScript somehow?

If anyone has any suggestions, I would really appreciate it, I am at a loss at the minute.

Comment: So even the `spiderfyOnMaxZoom` option for markercluster isn't good enough for your needs?

Comment: @John, unfortunately, not really. If I have, say, 100 pins on the same street, when I click on it spiderfys and it still looks quite messy. I'd like if I could somehow represent these pins as one pin, and then have the images from each pin inside this one pin.